# What is the right way to maintain a modified version of some open source project from github?

Tags: git, github, workflow, branch

I forked a project A to my own account.
And I modified it, and I used the modified the version.

Since this is customize not some optimization, I choose not to pull request.

I choose a pattern to keep sync while i can use my modified version:

1. I add a new remote 'my' which point to my repo(my forked repo).
2. So there are 2 remotes, 'origin' to the original version, 'my' to mine
3. I create a new branch, called 'mine'
4. anytime I want to keep up to the original version, i go to master branch, then use "git pull origin master", then I go to 'my' and merge 'master'
5. But most of the time, I will stay under 'my' and use things like 'git push my mine'

This is the right pattern that fits my need?

Comment: It's a good pattern. Just make sure you don't get confused with the remote and branch names. I like using github user names for remotes when it's across forks or `upstream` for the upstream version and user names for other forks. I would maintain `master` in parallel and use branches for your changes. You don't need to switch branches and pull to merge upstream: You can do `git fetch origin master; git merge origin/master mine`.

Comment: @kba aha, thanks for the tips, very helpful!